# Jquery Sortable, on Drag breaks float of Listobjects to next line

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

When I drag a list object, the rest of the row will "fall down" to the next row which it shouldn't. Any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/8mvLT/1/

```
$(function() {
    $("#sort").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
    }});
});
```

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/8mvLT/2/ 
Will check what's the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inlude float:left for your li items in your css, it will work

```
    #sort li {
         cursor:move;
         padding:5px;
         /*
         margin:0px 30px 2px 0px;
          height: auto;
         width: 99%;
          */
         margin:10px;
         width:20px;
         height:20px;
         border:1px solid orange;
         background:#eee;
          -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         border-radius: 5px;
         float:left;
      }
```